# How to get selected checkboxes in Grid using lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

```
var sel = chkGrid.Children.Cast<CheckBox>.Where(x => x.Selected);
```

I use this but not working.

Comment: Is this Winforms?  DataGridView?  What library and control type?

Comment: Is it CheckedListBox (WinForms)?

Answer (score 2):

`Cast` is a method - you've forgotten the brackets:

```
var sel = chkGrid.Children.Cast<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Selected);
```

If that doesn't work, perhaps some of your children aren't CheckBoxes, in which case you should use:

```
var sel = chkGrid.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Selected);
```

On the other hand, it's also possible that the check boxes aren't *direct* children of `chkGrid`. You may need to recurse into the child controls. It's hard to know more when we don't even know if this is WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET...

Comment: Can you please tell whether chkGrid.Children is used to get childrens upto one level or multiple level e.g. if we have a panel inside a row and then a checkbox may be.

Comment: @KSaini: It only gives the *direct* children, hence my comment that you may need to recurse.

Comment: So if we have a gridview (asp.net) and an item template  that directly contains a checkbox so in that i can use your code. Am i right?

Comment: @KSaini: I don't know how the containers work in ASP.NET, but that's almost certainly what's wrong.